# iPhone: Crash when reloading a tableview row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using the following section of code - it should be simple, but it's causing me a lot of trouble:

```
NSUInteger index[] = {1,0};   // top row of section one
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath     
indexPathWithIndexes:index length:2]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

The code crashes on the second line, with the error that "The number of rows in section zero is not equal to the number of rows in section zero before the update".

This error is true, I'm changing the number of rows in section zero. But surely this shouldn't effect whether or not I can reload a row in section 1!?

-

Am I misunderstanding how something works, or is something else going wrong somewhere? Any help or ideas are much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to update the `numberOfRowsInSection`.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return rowCount;
}
```

Comment: I am updating this. The frustrating bit is that the number of rows in section 1 stays the same before and after the update. Yes, the number of rows in section 0 changes, which causes the error. But surely I can reload section 1 while the number of rows in section 0 changes?

Comment: You should return no of rows for each section separate  .You can use a switch case in this method :  switch (indexPath.section) {
    case0:                                                              case1:                                                                         }

Comment: But the error says "The number of rows in section zero is not equal to the number of rows in section zero before the update" so i guess u are trying to update section 0 somewhere. Make sure you update the rows based on the section

Comment: Try to use this `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];` for indexPath

Comment: @rony I'm already doing this. I'm not all that new to iOS programming - as far as I can see, it's giving me an error about something completely different because the line of code I'm updating has nothing to do with section zero.

Comment: @7KV7 I've tried that too. I've also tried [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; and the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing (reloading) the number of rows in section 0 (probably by deleting or adding some rows in it) then -

> (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView
>   *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

is called to get the new number of rows. Here you need to return the correct number of rows i.e. one row less, if you deleted a row in section zero.

So basically, if you were returning [someArray count] for number of rows in section 0, you need to update this someArray as well.

Comment: I'm already doing this - the number of rows in section 0 changes, while in 1 it stays constant. I'm trying to reload the first row in section 1, but I'm getting an error related to section 0.

Comment: Lets say initially you have 5 rows in section 0. And you are returning 5 as number of rows in section 0 of the datasource method.
You said, you change the number of rows in section 0. Thus, the numberOfRowsInSection: method gets called again to get the updated rows for each section.

Here, you are not supposed to return 5 now. You need to return the updated value i.e. the new number of rows in section 0.

The error says that clearly.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this has nothing to do with section 1. But the problem is the datasource method numberOfRowsInSection: needs updated number of rows in section 0 (since you updated number of rows in section 0)

Comment: Thanks - yes, I understand this. After a bit of playing around it turns out it's actually something to do with the subtleties of how tableviews work - I'm calling the above code in viewWillAppear - which it turns out I can't do. I've come up with a workaround and will explain the subtlety in an answer later :)